# Enabling syntax colouring in ViewVC for SVN

Tags: svn, syntax-highlighting, mime, viewvc

I have just installed ViewVC 1.1.21 on a machine hosting a SVN repository that was migrated from an old CVS.

I wanted to enable syntax colouring for source files (Java, properties and XML files) as Eclipse does. I have installed both `python-Pygments` and `python3-Pygments` no matter the difference between the two. I also set `enable_syntax_coloration = 1`.

I have noticed that all files have `svn:mime-type` as `text/plain`.

Does the mime type affect syntax highlighting? Do I have to do something else to fix colouring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following process:

- Set `detect_encoding = 1` in viewvc.conf
- Set `enable_syntax_coloration = 1` in viewvc.conf

Here are the caveats:

> Requires 'chardet' module, and is currently used only by the syntax coloration logic -- if enabled -- for the 'markup' and 'annotate' views; see 'enable_syntax_coloration'.

If that fails, use the legacy process:

- Set `use_enscript = 0` in viewvc.conf
- Set `use_highlight = 1` in viewvc.conf
- Find `highlight_path` in viewvc.conf

  - Uncomment it
  - Do `ls` on the value
  - If Pygments is there, do nothing
  - Otherwise, use `which` to find the path to Pygments, then set that as the new value
- Enable mime_types_files in viewvc.conf
- Find `mime_types_files` in viewvc.conf

  - Do `ls` on the value
  - If `mime.types` is there, do nothing
  - Otherwise, use `find` to find the path to `mime.types`, then set that as the new value

**References**

- [Use a single, good, Python-module-based syntax highlighter](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/long_list.cgi?issuelist=349)
- [Syntax highlight/colorize scripts without extensions](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/long_list.cgi?issuelist=495)
- [Recognize XML as Text](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/long_list.cgi?issuelist=298)
- [ViewVC should display Unicode files correctly](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/long_list.cgi?issuelist=460)
- [Sample viewvc.conf](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/showattachment.cgi/125/viewvc.conf)
- [viewvc.py Source](http://viewvc.tigris.org/source/browse/viewvc/trunk/lib/viewvc.py?view=markup)
- [Use the 'chardet' module where available and enabled by configuration](http://viewvc.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4252&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=3053678#)

Answer (score 0):

I need to add on the viewvc.conf this configuration

default_file_view = markup

Best Regards Kandy